# Is it possible to obtain someone's private IP through IP logging?

Tags: vpn, ip

Let's say Alice sends Bob a link through email, social media etc. The link logs Bob's IP if Bob clicks the link.

If I'm correct, the IP Alice gets is Bob's public/ISP IP address. Is it possible for Alice to obtain Bob's private/client IP with only a link, or does Alice have to do more than that to obtain Bob's private IP (Evil twin for example).

I also assume that this all becomes obsolete if Bob uses a VPN to mask his identity.

Comment: What is the purpose of obtaining Bob's private IP?

Comment: I was wondering if people could actually find your private IP(which would be the closest to your current location) through a simple link that logs visitor's IP addresses, which contains no 
further exploits.

Comment: Private IPs have absolutely nothing to do with one's location.

Comment: I feel so dumb, so there's actually no possibility to get ahold of Bob's current exact location, if Alice found out only his public IP?

Comment: You are talking about completely different things. A private IP is the IP used within a private network (like a home), and that IP never hits the Internet. `192.168.1.1` is a private IP. And millions of home routers have that exact IP. If Alice, somewhere out in the Internet, learns that Bob has an IP of `192.168.1.1`, it is completely meaningless to her. And it cannot be used to physically locate Bob. Bob's ***public IP*** which is assigned by Bob's ISP can be used to locate Bob to a general geographic location (like the city).

Comment: I thought a private IP was assigned to the location of example; your house, like how your Public IP shows ISP location, hence the reason I thought if it was possible to go even further after you've found out someone's Public IP in order to exactly pinpoint the location. Thanks!

Comment: @Pluto477 No, a public IP is your assigned IP by the ISP. A private IP is entirely local to your LAN and you share the same private IP with a lot of other people. For example, your private IP is probably somewhere in 192.168.0.0/16. Maybe 10.0.0.0/8 if you have a big network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a networking question and the OSI layered technology model comes into play. There are a lot of moving parts in your question and it is not well defined.

It matters what the link does and the delivery method.

If the point is for Alice's server the record the IP of Bob's visiting client, then all Alice will get is the IP used *to route Bob's traffic to Alice's server*. So, if Bob is at home behind a router, then Alice will not see Bob's private IP because that IP is not used to route the traffic over the Internet.

If the link triggers a process on Bob's device to gather the private IP and send that as data to Alice's server, then Alice can get that data, and even a VPN will not help here because the data is being collected on Bob's device itself before the VPN or the network comes into play at all.

So, the question about the situation is what the link actually does.

Mentioning "evil twin" complicates the scenario. If Alice can get that close, physically, to Bob and the network Bob is on, then many other options are available, including joining the network and scanning, and other techniques.

Comment: Thanks, but reading about how a VPN would not help, isn't it quite concerning how people could track your private IP if the link/site was further exploited to gather the private IP? And I assume this requires Bob to open a malicious file of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricky javascript techniques that can be used to pickup the user's private IP address.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript for information on some of these.

If Bob clicks the link, and the page loads in his browser - then javascript on this page can pickup his private IP and send it back to Alice's server.

Comment: It should be noted that e.g. Chrome gives a false reading by default.